# Get an average of variables in MySQL query as well as SUMS

Tags: php, mysql, sql

(This is a rewrite of my previous question which may not have been clear enough)

I have a query for a MYSQL database which is as follows:

```
SELECT name,
SUM(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Dec, 2011', 1,0)) AS `month1`, 
SUM(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Jan, 2012', 1,0)) AS `month2`, 
SUM(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Feb, 2012', 1,0)) AS `month3`, 
etc...
```

Which gets me a series of results like - month1=55, month2=70, month3=89 etc

In the query is a line -

```
COUNT(*) AS total FROM table order by total
```

Which effectively gives me a total of month1+month2+month3+ etc

However I also need to get an average of those same monthly totals

So I need a MySQL function that would effectively be something like

```
AVG (month1, month2, month3 etc)
```

which would give the average of 55,70,89

Can anyone help?

Thanks very much

AS REQUESTED, COMPLETE QUERY IS -

```
SELECT name, 
    SUM(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Nov, 2011', 1,0))/list*1000 AS `month1`, 
    SUM(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Dec, 2011', 1,0))/list*1000 AS `month2`, 
    SUM(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Jan, 2012', 1,0))/list*1000 AS `month3`, 
    SUM(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Feb, 2012', 1,0))/list*1000 AS `month4`, 
    SUM(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Mar, 2012', 1,0))/list*1000 AS `month5`, 
    SUM(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Apr, 2012', 1,0))/list*1000 AS `month6`, 
    SUM(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'May, 2012', 1,0))/list*1000 AS `month7`, 
    SUM(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Jun, 2012', 1,0))/list*1000 AS `month8`, 
    SUM(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Jul, 2012', 1,0))/list*1000 AS `month9`, 
    SUM(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Aug, 2012', 1,0))/list*1000 AS `month10`, 
    SUM(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Sep, 2012', 1,0))/list*1000 AS `month11`, 
    SUM(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Oct, 2012', 1,0))/list*1000 AS `month12`, 
    COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM table 
group by name 
order by total
```

Comment: i believe `SUM(IF(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date) = 201112), 1, 0) as month1,` will be much faster

Comment: Can you post a complete query instead of small snippets?

Comment: Thanks Peter, I'll give that a try. By the way, the 'date' although called that is actually a DATETIME - will that make a difference?

Comment: Martijn, just posted full query above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can use a subquery -

```
SELECT name,
  `month1`, `month2`, `month3`
  total,
  (`month1` + `month2` + `month3`) / 3 AS `avg`
FROM
  (SELECT name, 
    SUM(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Nov, 2011', 1,0))/list*1000 AS `month1`, 
    SUM(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Dec, 2011', 1,0))/list*1000 AS `month2`, 
    SUM(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Jan, 2012', 1,0))/list*1000 AS `month3`, 
    COUNT(*) AS total 
  FROM table 
  GROUP BY name 
  ORDER BY total
  ) t
```

---

But I'd suggest you to use something like this -

```
SELECT month, AVG(cnt) cnt FROM
  (SELECT MONTH(DATE) month, COUNT(*) cnt FROM table1 GROUP BY month) t
GROUP BY month WITH ROLLUP
```

...you only should add year support.

Comment: Thanks Devart. I'm trying your suggestion, but cant get the syntax for the subquery correct.  Within the Subquery, ie (SELECT name, ...  do I include the COUNT (*) AS TOTAL or is that outside? And should there be a closing comma after the SUMs?  The complete query is now posted above if that helps.  Thanks again

Comment: That COUNT must be inside the subquery. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
SELECT name, month1,month2,...., AVG(month1,month2,...,month12) as Average FROM
(
SELECT name,
SUM(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Dec, 2011', 1,0)) AS `month1`, 
SUM(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Jan, 2012', 1,0)) AS `month2`, 
SUM(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Feb, 2012', 1,0)) AS `month3`, 
etc...
) as t
```